# Confirmation Dialog from MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want  to read excel and count number of rows in excel and show user message to confirm number of rows to upload. I was just looking for help how to show message from controller after reading excel count.

```
public ActionResult UploadAccountCreation(FormCollection form)
{
     if (Request.Files.Count> 0 || Request.Files[0].ContentLength > 0)
     {


        // Read Excel Count
        // Show Message to user "Are you sure you want to upload X number of account"
        if(yes)
        {
           // Code for yes
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: If this information is only available server-side then the "confirmation" would involve redirecting the user to a confirmation page of some kind and then an action invoked from that page would perform the resulting process.  Server-side code can't directly prompt the user in the way you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the javascript method like in this [post](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Server-Side-Yes-No-Confirmation-Message-Box-in-Controller-in-ASPNet-MVC-Razor.aspx) to get the alert with **Yes** Or **No** options based on your excel count.

Comment: Is your issue fixed?